# Which Is a Better Way of Handling Custom Exception Messages

Tags: java, exception, message

I have a code that has some custom exceptions and was wondering what is the best/efficient way to handle the error messages of an exception.

like this?

```
public class coolExceptionName extends Exception{
     public coolExceptionName(String a){
         super(a);
     }
}
```

**or**

```
public class coolExceptionName extends Exception{
     @Override
     public String toString(){
        return "Error Message";
     }
}
```

Which one is considered as standard practice?

Comment: I believe the first method is a better way of handling exceptions as you can give different messages for custom exceptions. You can also include a status code in the `coolExceptionName(HttpStatus status, String message)` constructor to define `HTTP` status codes like `403`, `400`, `500`, `404` catering to various errors that may arise in your code.

Comment: 1st is more useful than 2nd one. In 1st you can give error message as per your error event but in 2nd due to same message for all error it is not good to figure out actul problem in code.

Comment: Like others suggested, I would also add some 'Error-Code' / prefix in your custom exception.

Comment: Say i have some standard messages stored in .properties file, Then?

Comment: You can use `@Value` annotation to read values from `.properties` file and declare a `String` variable in your class which will hold the error message value -> `@Value("${notfound.error}") String errorMessageForNotFound;`. When you call the constructor to display the message while throwing the exception, just use the `errorMessageForNotFound` variable in it if that makes sense.